# Discord.js DM User kicked

Tags: bots, discord.js

Okay so I am having trouble trying to DM a user who was kicked from the server right now it DM's the person who kicked the member. I don't know what I did wrong but I want the bot to DM the user who was kicked so they know why they were kicked frokm the server

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { red_dark } = require("../../colors.json");

module.exports = {
        name: "kick",
        description: "Kick a user from the guild!",
        usage: "!kick",
        category: "moderation",
        accessableby: "Moderator",
        aliases: ["k"],

    run: async (bot, message, args, user) => {
      try{
  if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
      if (message.mentions.users.size != 0) {
        if (message.mentions.members.first().kickable) {
            let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
            if(!reason) return message.channel.send("No reason was provided!")

            else {
          message.member.send("This is a test message")
          message.mentions.members.first().kick().then(m => {

            message.channel.send(`**${m.user.username}** has been kicked from **${message.guild.name}**. Bye bye!`)
          });
          }


            } else {
          message.channel.send(`:x: **${message.mentions.user.first().username}** is too priveledged for me to kick.`);
        }
      } else {
        message.channel.send(':x: Please tag the user you would like to kick.')
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.send(`:x: **${message.author.username}**, You do not have permission to kick. You must have the \`Kick Members\` permission.`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    message.channel.send(`:x: Either I am unable to kick **${message.mentions.users.first().username},** or I do not have permission to kick members.`);
  }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently send a the DM to `message.member`. What you would need to do it to send it to the same person you actually kick, which you currently do with `message.mentions.members.first().kick()`.

So with that clarified, you need to do `message.mentions.members.first().send("This is a test message")`